# Listview não repetir registros

Tags: delphi, listview, txt

Tenho um arquivo `txt` com vários registros dentro, preciso de algo que na hora que a função for adicionar para o `ListView` esses registros, não deixem adicionar itens repetidos. Para fazer isso, ele poderia usar uma determinada coluna e comparar. Dentro do txt o delimitador que eu uso e um @.

**Código:**

```
 var
  Linhas:  TStringList;
  Colunas: TStringList;
  i,l:       integer;
  Item: TListItem;
  begin
  Linhas := TStringList.Create;
  Colunas := TStringlist.Create;
  Linhas.LoadFromFile('c:\clientes.txt');

        for i := 0 to Linhas.Count-1 do
        begin
           Colunas.Text := StringReplace(Linhas[i],'@',Char(13)+Char(10),[rfReplaceAll]);
           Item := Form1.LV.Items.Add;
           l := l + 1;
           Item.Caption := inttostr(l);
           Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[1]);
           Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[0]);
           Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[7]);
           Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[2]);
        end;
        end;
```

Comment: Tente SubItems.IndexOf(Colunas[1]); se retornar < 0 quer dizer que não encontrou, se retornar >= 0 quer dizer que encontrou

Comment: @Passella, e se ele encontrar repetidos, como posso fazer pra ele apagar todos deixando somente 1 ?

Comment: você tem que fazer essa verificação quando inserir o item

Comment: Veja amigo @Passella:     if Item.SubItems.IndexOf(Colunas[2]) <= 0 then
       begin
       Item.Caption := inttostr(l);
       Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[1]);
       Item.SubItems.Add(Colunas[0]);

Comment: Não deu certo, ele ta adicionando repetido!

Comment: mostre seu código inteiro, não tem muito o que fazer sem ver ele.

Comment: @Passella, o código é aquele mesmo e cima, com a diferença que eu inseri a regra que você passou antes do Item.Caption, entende ?

Comment: @Passella, alguma sugestão ? nossa to apanhando demais nisso..

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma solução usando uma lista auxiliar para evitar ficar escaneando o `TListView` inteiro. Dá pra otimizar o código depois, de acordo com o uso prático que você for fazer.

Troque o `Colunas[2]` pela coluna desejada na comparação nas partes que tratam da `ListaAuxiliar`.

```
var
   Linhas:        TStringList;
   Colunas:       TStringList;
   ListaAuxiliar: TStringList;
   i, l:          integer;
   Item:          TListItem;
begin
   Linhas        := TStringList.Create;
   Colunas       := TStringlist.Create;
   ListaAuxiliar := TStringList.Create;
   Linhas.LoadFromFile( 'c:\clientes.txt' );
   for i := 0 to Linhas.Count - 1 do
   begin
      Colunas.Text := StringReplace( Linhas[i], '@', Char(13) + Char(10), [rfReplaceAll] );

      if ListaAuxiliar.IndexOf( Colunas[2] ) = -1 then
      begin
         ListaAuxiliar.Add( Colunas[2] );
         Item := Form1.LV.Items.Add;
         l := l + 1;
         Item.Caption := inttostr( l );
         Item.SubItems.Add( Colunas[1] );
         Item.SubItems.Add( Colunas[0] );
         Item.SubItems.Add( Colunas[7] );
         Item.SubItems.Add( Colunas[2] );
      end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: infelizmente não deu certo, ele continua repetindo os itens.....eu tentei até pegar pelo valor que seria a Coluna[4] e mesmo assim não deu certo.

Comment: Adicione a sua questão um "clientes.txt" exemplo, por favor.

Comment: @user7605 lembrou de trocar o Colunas[4] nos dois lugares?